# SOQL Childrecord-rollup for PersonAccounts

Tags: soql, relationships, person-accounts

What is the best way to get the number of childrecords on a personaccount with the PersonContactId as Id field, the lookup being a contact lookup?

I have the object Newsletter, with a contact lookup field and want a SOQL which gives me personaccounts with the number of related newsletter.

I tried:
`[SELECT ID, PersonContactId, (SELECT Id FROM Newsletter__r) FROM Account]`, but it only tells me that it doesnt understand the relationship.

I also tried getting the it with a separate SOQL:
`[SELECT Id, count(Id) FROM Newsletter__c WHERE ContactId__c in :setPersonAccounts]`, but I get the error "Field must be grouped or aggregated: Id" and if I group by id I get the error "Grouped field should not be aggregated: Id".

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that .just used Newsletter__r( child relationship name )

List AccountList = [SELECT Name, (SELECT id FROM Newsletter__r) FROM Account];
for (Account Acc: AccountList ) {
    // do something with it...
    Acc.Newsletter__r.size();
}

Comment: (SELECT id FROM Newsletter__r)  isnt working. The Relationship is a lookup from custom object to contact. Salesforce seems to not understand that i want to reference personaccounts.